# Google Apis sendVerificationCode returns backendError 39

Tags: firebase, google-identity-toolkit

All of a sudden the sendVerificationCode auth (/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode) POST call returns 503 backendError.

I couldn't find the error code in any of the Google API documentation as well. Appreciated any help. Thank you.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "Error code: 39",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Error code: 39",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This certainly is a Server error. I think the best way to find more information about the cause of this error is by reaching out to the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support)

Comment: What's the purpose of the link in the question? It's not accessible and and is dead, which doesn't appear to be related to the actual question. Or is it?

Comment: @jay the url is the one called by the firebase auth from client.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what's wrong? I am having the same issue, started suddenly occurring about an hour ago.

Comment: Nope. Its intermittent but persistent.

Comment: Thanks, @jkumaranc. Mine started working again too. I opened a ticket with Firebase Support. I will report back when I hear something.

Comment: Thanks @enlightenedOne. Appreciate that.

Comment: @jkumaranc - I just received the response and it's what I predicted. Basically, they say it happens when you make too many authentication requests from a single IP in a short period of time. Which I did during my testing. They suggested whitelisting your phone number in the Firebase console. This resolved my issue, and hope it will resolve yours.

Comment: Thanks @enlightenedOne. Thats a great news. We will try the same.